# Sending commands to FWTools via Matlab?

Tags: matlab, map-projections

I am trying to use Matlab to send commands to FWTools in order to project a bunch of .shp files.

I am able to start FWTools from Matlab but I cant figure out how to send it commands without my interaction.

So far FWTools starts and my matlab command window and acts like the FWTools shell. I type commands and it will run, but I want to be able to send them in my .m file. Once FWTools starts up, my script will not continue to the next line of code.

My code so far:

```
cmd = 'ogr2ogr -s_srs "EPSG:4326" -t_srs "EPSG:3006" out_sweref99tm.shp in_wgs84.shp';
system('C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe \K "d:\FWTools2.4.7\setfw.bat" ')
sprintf('%s',cmd) % try to send cmd to matlab command window aka FWTools
```

I also tried to put the cmd into my system call but that returned an error since it appears that I am trying to call FWTools with a super long string afterwards :(

```
cmd = 'ogr2ogr -s_srs "EPSG:4326" -t_srs "EPSG:3006" out_sweref99tm.shp in_wgs84.shp';
system(['C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe \K "d:\FWTools2.4.7\setfw.bat" ',cmd])
```

The reason I am using FWTools is that I am projecting from WGS84 to SWEREF99TM and (from my understanding) its not easy to get the final projection via Matlab's mapping toolbox. Please correct me if I am wrong as I would love to keep it to Matlab.

And if possible, I would like to stay in Matlab and not move to Python.

Thanks.
Norris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The call of `C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe` is not necessary.

Try this:

```
cmd = 'ogr2ogr -s_srs "EPSG:4326" -t_srs "EPSG:3006" out_sweref99tm.shp in_wgs84.shp';
system(['d: && cd d:\FWTools2.4.7\ && setfw.bat ',cmd])
```

or if you actually need to pass your parameters after the first call and not with:

```
system(['d: && cd d:\FWTools2.4.7\ && setfw.bat && ',cmd])
```

Maybe you can post a screenshot of how it looks like when you do it manually.

---

requested explanation:

The `&&` operator is implicating that the following command is executed "in the next line". It's like you press `enter` in the cmd window and then you have to type the next command.

For example `cd d:\FWTools2.4.7\` does never work directly, as the default is usually "c:". So firstly have to type `d:` and in the next step you change to your folder `cd d:\FWTools2.4.7\`